# What is the UserManager.SecurityStampAsync() equivalent when using Azure AD authentication?

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, adfs

When User's permissions or roles changes, I want to invalidate their authentication cookie or token and ensure their new access privileges are immediately effectuated. 
I understand in ASP.NET MVC when using Individual User Accounts authentication, there is the UserManager.SecurityStampAsync() method to carry this out.

I'm not sure if I Azure AD and refresh tokens have a similar mechanism in place and if the time to refresh the User's privileges can be controlled. Also I would like to know if User is forced to log out before seeing latest permissions.